# Python dataframe assignment

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have quite a difficult issue to explain, I'll try my best.
I have a function a() that calls function b() and passes to b() a dataframe (called "df_a").
I learned that this is done by reference, meaning that when/if in inside function b() I add a new column to the input dataframe, this will also modify the original one. For example:

```
def b(df_b):
   df_b['Country'] = "not sure"

def a():
   df_a = pd.DataFrame({"Name":['Mark','Annie'],  'Age':[30,28]})
   b(df_a)
   print(df_a) # this dataframe will now have the column "Country"
```

So far so good. The problem is that today I realized that if inside b() we merge the dataframe with another dataframe, this create a new local dataframe.

```
def b(df_b):
       df_c = pd.DataFrame({"Name":['Mark','Annie'],  'Country':['Brazil','Japan']})
       df_b = pd.merge(df_b, df_c, left_on = 'Name', right_on='Name', how='left')
def a():
       df_a = pd.DataFrame({"Name":['Mark','Annie'],  'Age':[30,28]})
       b(df_a)
       print(df_a) # this dataframe will *not* have the column "Country"
```

So my question is, how to I make sure in this second example the column "Country" is also assigned to the original df_a dataframe, without returning it back?
(I would prefer *not* to use  "return df_b" inside function b() since I would have to change the logic in many many parts of the code.
Thank you

Comment: In your last sentence, Did you mean " I would not prefer to use"?

Comment: yes, you're actually right

Answer (score 1):

I have modified the function `b()` and `a()` so the changes made in `b` are returned back to `a`

```py
def b(df_b):
    df_c = pd.DataFrame({"Name":['Mark','Annie'],  'Country':['Brazil','Japan']})
    df_b = pd.merge(df_b, df_c, left_on = 'Name', right_on='Name', how='left')
    return df_b
def a():
    df_a = pd.DataFrame({"Name":['Mark','Annie'],  'Age':[30,28]})
    df_a = b(df_a)
    print(df_a)
```

`**Output:** a()`

```
    Name  Age Country
0   Mark   30  Brazil
1  Annie   28   Japan
```

Comment: thanks Suraj but you have used the return function and as mentioned above that's currently not an option on my end since I trusted every change applied to df_b would have also be reflected in df_a

Comment: I think the problem is that when you merge it, your not doing the operation inplace, hence a new dataframe is created, which points to a different location in memory. So `df_b` and `df_a` have different values. Also `pandas.merge` does not have `inplace` paramter.

Comment: right, so how can I do something similar to the inplace parameter without creating a new dataframe that is stored in a new location in the memory?

Comment: I am unaware of such a technique man, I'll let you know if i find out.